# (Laravel 5.6, vue) Axios 401 error with PUT,POST,PATCH on Safari

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, laravel-5.6, laravel-passport

Using only `Safari` (latest version High Sierra) I get a `401` error on every request that is not GET.

I tested the options request with postman and it returns a `200 OK` response.

The problem is that the Authorization header is not sent.
This is the request:
[safari request and response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lmgn8.png)

I tested it on Chrome, Firefox, and Opera and it works.
Here's the code, note that I'm not using the short version of `axios`(.post,.get) as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50749444/get-a-401-error-with-post-and-put-laravel-passport-vue-axios)

```
      let url = (edit)?'/api/things/'+vm.nthing.id:'/api/things';
      let method = (edit)?'patch':'put';

      axios({
        method:method,
        url:url,
        headers:vm.headers,
        data:{
          final: vm.nthing.final,
          note: vm.nthing.note
        }
      })
      .then(res=>{
        //Some modal stuff
      })
      .catch(err=>{
        console.log(err);
      });
```

The headers var is:

```
headers:{
    "Authorization":"Bearer "+this.$auth.getToken()
  },
```

Comment: same error! Any solution about this please?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so apparently objects with a string property are ignored in `Safari`, so the *authorization* element in the header was never passed, hence the `401` error.

**Doesn't work**

```
let headers={
 "Authorization":"abcdef...."
}
```

**Works**

```
let headers={
 Authorization:"abcdef...."
}
```

Also be careful about trailing slashes in axios's url.